# Merge alternate elements from two lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a Prolog predicate `mergealt(X,Y,Z)` that succeeds if the list Z is a merger of alternate elements from the lists X and Y.

The input and output will like below:

```
?- mergealt([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8],Z).
Z = [1, 7, 3] .
?- mergealt([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9],Z).
Z = [1, 7, 3, 9] .
?- mergealt([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,10],Z).
Z = [1, 7, 3, 9] .
```

I don't really understand recursion. How can I get started on this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prolog can be considered the 'flagman' of declarative languages.
So try to describe your problem, top down:

```
mergealt(X, Y, Z) :-
  'take first element from X and put it in Z',
  'discard first element from Y',
  'mergealt rest-of-X and rest-of-Y, but exchange them'.
```

First step can't be accomplished if there are no elements in X.
This fact highlights the recursion termination case. Originally, Prolog didn't used `if then else`, instead alternatives are stated as different rules:

```
mergealt([], _Y, []).
```

Here you can see that `pattern matching` on first argument it's the key to distinguish alternatives, and contextually, Z get *bound* to an empty list. Y is unused, so it's marked as *anonymus* place holder, just to avoid a warning.

Then this simpler case suggests that we should use pattern matching to accomplish those verbose descriptions. See if you can complete the procedure with these guidelines:

```
mergealt([X|Xs], Y, [X|Zs]) :-
  % take first element from X and put it in Z : done in the head
  % discard first element from Y : see below
  % mergealt rest-of-X and rest-of-Y, but exchange them'. : make your recursive call

discard_first_element([_|Rest], Rest).
% why is this necessary? do you see where it fails if we don't specify this case?
discard_first_element([], []).
```

Answer (score 2):

- Notice that the result always starts with the first element of the first list.
- This means that, if the first list is empty, you know the answer right away.
- Also notice that, if it isn't empty, we already know the first item of the result, so we need to use mergealt to compute the rest.  But "the rest" will have the second item of the second list as the first item of the result, and as we said above, that means that a call to mergealt to compute it would have to have that be the first item of the first list (yeah, this is the tricky part).